# How to print and attribute integers into an array in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code

I'm trying to just print these 3 integers, but I get the error "-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --". When I compare my code to others that work, I can't see exactly what I'm doing wrong. This looks ok to me:

```
.data
    a: .word 3, 2, 1
main:   
    li $s0, 0 #i = 0
    li $s1, 3 #iterations = 3
    la $s2, a #s2 = adress of arr[0]
loop:
    beq $s0, $s1, end #if i == 3, ends
    lw $t0, 0($s2) #loads value of a[0] into t0
    addi $s2, $s2, 4 #goes to next element of array
    addi $s0, $s0, 1 #i++
    
    
    #some printing function I found online
    li $v0, 4
    lw $a0, 0($t0)
    syscall
    
    j loop
    
end:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are dereferencing the pointer to the array twice, which does not make sense in this context, since one dereference is sufficient to get an integer value from an integer array.  If you had an array of *pointers*, then a second dereference might be indicated.  Not sure what simulator you're using or its configuration, but it should have given a memory access error on the 2nd dereference, since a small integer is not a valid pointer.
- A program is supposed to tell the operating environment or simulator to quit when it's done — yours doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me how I am doing that? I know I la a in s2, which in my understanding saves address of a in s2 and I also lw s2 into t0, which means to put the value of s2 in t0.

Comment: Yes, that is the first dereference, but you're also showing lw into a0 from t0,

Comment: I tried to fix that by commenting out the first lw, but that didn't work. How could I fix that?

Comment: 1) You're using the wrong syscall, that is for printing a string and you have an integer. http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html  2) The syscall#1, which prints an integer, takes the integer argument in a0, so if you don't have it in a0, then move it there.